# Replace href of 'Add Another Row' button in Django admin TabularInline

Tags: python, jquery, django, django-admin

I have a TabularInline, which allows users to quickly edit certain fields in the Django admin panel. However, when clicking the 'Add Another ...' button, I want to re-direct the user to a new link, instead of adding another row. Here is the code for my TabularInline:

```
class CustomInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = CustomModel
    extra = 0
    verbose_name = "Custom Model"
    fields = ['title', 'pub_date', 'published']
    show_change_link = True
```

I've tried to use jQuery to select the relevant element so that I can replace the link's href. However, it doesn't seem to be finding the relevant element.

When I inspect the form in Chrome dev tools, I can see the element (screenshot below):

[image]

However, when I try and select the element using the following jQuery code, I'm getting nothing back.

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
  let fiveQWGroup = $("div#fiveqw_set-group div.tabular fieldset.module table tbody tr:last-child");
  console.log(fiveQWGroup)
});
```

The relevant selector doesn't seem to be appearing in the source code for that page either.

So, my question is, how can I change the href of the button to the required href instead?